# Show that $f_n \to 0$ everywhere but not in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

> Let $f_n = \chi_{[n, n+1]}$. Show that the sequence $(f_n)$ converges everywhere to the $0$-function, but that it does not converge in measure.

For every $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists some $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x \not\in [n, n+1]$ for all $n \ge N$. So clearly we have that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ $$|f_n (x) - 0| < \varepsilon$$ whenever $n \ge N.$ So $f_n \to 0$ everywhere.

Is this correct?

I am not sure how to show that it does not converge to $0$ in measure though. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Note that $f_n$ cannot converge in measure if $|f_n-f_m|$ does not converge to zero in measure. Write out this condition explicitly and you can solve this exercise.

Comment: @PaxKivimae . Thanks for the hint! Is my first part correct though? :)

Comment: Yes. First part is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n$, the measure of the set $\{|f_{n}|\geq 1/2\}$ is $1$, so the $f_{n}$'s cannot converge to $0$ in measure.